# Automatically add all files in a folder to a target using CMake?

Tags: visual-c++, cmake, cross-platform

I am considering switching a cross platform project from separate build management systems in Visual C++, XCode and makefiles to CMake.

One essential feature I need is to add automatically all files in a directory to a target. While this is easy to do with make, it is not easily doable with Visual C++ and XCode (correct me if I am wrong). Is it possible to do it in directly in CMake? How?

Comment: Btw. in In Visual Studio, at least in C# projects, there's a toolbar button in the project explorer, named show all files. It makes all sub-directories of a project visible, greyed out if they don't contain any files logically included in the project. You can include these directories via the context menu, which includes all source files inside them, recursively :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use all \*.c files in a directory with the Cmake build system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2110795/how-to-use-all-c-files-in-a-directory-with-the-cmake-build-system)

Answer (score 303, accepted):

As of CMake 3.1+ the developers *strongly discourage* users from using `file(GLOB` or `file(GLOB_RECURSE` to collect lists of source files.

> **Note:** We do not recommend using GLOB to collect a list of source files from your source tree. If no CMakeLists.txt file changes when a source is added or removed then the generated build system cannot know when to ask CMake to regenerate. The CONFIGURE_DEPENDS flag may not work reliably on all generators, or if a new generator is added in the future that cannot support it, projects using it will be stuck. Even if CONFIGURE_DEPENDS works reliably, there is still a cost to perform the check on every rebuild.

See the [documentation here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/file.html#glob).

There are two goods answers ([[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18538444/2137996), [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1060061/2137996)) here on SO detailing the reasons to manually list source files.

---

It is possible. E.g. with `file(GLOB`:

```cmake
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

file(GLOB helloworld_SRC
     "*.h"
     "*.cpp"
)

add_executable(helloworld ${helloworld_SRC})
```

Note that this requires *manual* re-running of `cmake` if a source file is added or removed, since the generated build system does not know when to ask CMake to regenerate, and doing it at every build would increase the build time.

As of CMake 3.12, you can pass the `CONFIGURE_DEPENDS` flag to `file(GLOB` to automatically check and reset the file lists any time the build is invoked. You would write:

```cmake
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)

file(GLOB helloworld_SRC CONFIGURE_DEPENDS "*.h" "*.cpp")
```

This at least lets you avoid manually re-running CMake every time a file is added.

Comment: An alternative to manually re-running cmake is to touch the CMakeLists.txt file before running make.

Comment: Alternative to `GLOB`: [`file(GLOB_RECURSE variable [RELATIVE path]
     [FOLLOW_SYMLINKS] [globbing expressions]...)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/file.html).

Comment: >"We do not recommend using GLOB to collect a list of source files from your source tree. If no CMakeLists.txt file changes when a source is added or removed then the generated build system cannot know when to ask CMake to regenerate."

This is no longer recommeneded in CMAKE3.7 docs linked about by Hand1Cloud

Comment: @triple `GLOB`, not `GLOB_RECURSE`.

Comment: whats the alternative to GLOB then?

Comment: @Shayne you add the actual list of named files to cmake.  It's a huge win in building bigger projects, and a trivial cost for smaller projects.

Comment: And an absolute nightmare when trying to port an existing project with thousands of files.

Comment: @Shayne you've definitely got it the wrong way around.  If you have thousands of files, you really want to do things the CMake way, and have them all named in the cmake files correctly.  It's a trivial shell script to build them.  If you really, deeply don't want to do things the cmake way, you probably don't want to use cmake at all.  It's not the only game in town.

Comment: Its not the only game in town .... except when it is. (Ie using C-Lion or integrating into an existing cmake system

Comment: A better way since v3.1 is suggested here:
**target_sources()**
https://crascit.com/2016/01/31/enhanced-source-file-handling-with-target_sources/

Comment: It doesn't work at all, tried multiple time and didn't work

Comment: "Note that this requires _manual_ re-running of cmake if a source file is added or removed", but wouldn't you need to _manually_ modify the CMakeLists.txt file in this case anyway?? And then still rerun cmake on the modified file?

Comment: I laughed reading this answer. I've come across countless packages where it uses globs along with the obligatory comment "do as I say not as I do."

Comment: I am shocked by how primitive modern tools are. CMake, for instance, could optionally just query Git and detect changes, or keep track of the source changes inside the build directory. I'll never understand how CMake became so popular other than reports that it sucks less than the alternatives.

Answer (score 32):

The answer by Kleist certainly works, but there is an important caveat:

When you write a `Makefile` manually, you might generate a `SRCS` variable using a function to select all `.cpp` and `.h` files. If a source file is later added, re-running `make` will include it.

However, CMake (with a command like `file(GLOB ...)`) will explicitly generate a file list and place it in the auto-generated `Makefile`. If you have a new source file, you will need to re-generate the `Makefile` by re-running `cmake`.

edit: No need to remove the Makefile.

Comment: Can't cmake simply be re-run, which should remove/modify the out-of-date Makefile?

Comment: This isn't an answer, it's a comment about @Kleist's answer.

Comment: @Neowizard not in Stackoverflow terminology.

Comment: This comment is nice, but it's "standard", right? The asker is using cmake already, so suggesting make can be "smarter" isn't that helpful.

Comment: So is there way to add new source files and then build without re-running cmake?

Comment: I guess you can manually modify the `Makefile` auto-generated by CMake. But why?

Comment: create a bash /powershell script to output all .h .cpp files already in the format you need.
Script coming soon

Answer (score 9):

**Extension** for [@Kleist answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3201211/3440745):

Since CMake 3.12 additional option *CONFIGURE_DEPENDS* is [supported](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.12/command/file.html#glob) by commands `file(GLOB)` and `file(GLOB_RECURSE)`. With this option there is **no needs** to **manually** re-run CMake after addition/deletion of a source file in the directory - CMake will be re-run automatically on next building the project.

However, the option *CONFIGURE_DEPENDS* implies that corresponding directory will be re-checked every time building is requested, so **build** process would **consume more time** than without *CONFIGURE_DEPENDS*.

Even with *CONFIGURE_DEPENDS* option available CMake documentation still **does not recommend** using `file(GLOB)` or `file(GLOB_RECURSE)` for collect the sources.

Comment: "CMake documentation still does not recommend using `file(GLOB)` or `file(GLOB_RECURSE)` for collect the sources" What do they recommend then? Using something else to collect the sources or to manually list every single source file?

Comment: @Thomas: They recommend to manually list every source file. [That answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18538444/3440745) gives a great explanation of the recommendation.

Answer (score 2):

To use Visual Studio project hierarchy inside Clion with cmake:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
project(MyProject)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

file(GLOB APP_SOURCES */*.cpp)
foreach (testsourcefile ${APP_SOURCES})
    get_filename_component(testname ${testsourcefile} NAME_WLE)
    get_filename_component(dirname ${testsourcefile} DIRECTORY)
    file(GLOB dir_src CONFIGURE_DEPENDS
            "${dirname}/*.h"
            "${dirname}/*.cpp"
            )
    message("${testname}.cpp | ${dir_src}")
    add_executable("${testname}.cpp" ${dir_src})
endforeach (testsourcefile ${APP_SOURCES})
```

Answer (score -5):

So Why not use powershell to create the list of source files for you. Take a look at this script

```
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
    [string]$root 
)

if (-not (Test-Path  -Path $root)) {    
throw "Error directory does not exist"
}

#get the full path of the root
$rootDir = get-item -Path $root
$fp=$rootDir.FullName;


$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $root -Recurse -File | 
         Where-Object { ".cpp",".cxx",".cc",".h" -contains $_.Extension} | 
         Foreach {$_.FullName.replace("${fp}\","").replace("\","/")}

$CMakeExpr = "set(SOURCES "

foreach($file in $files){

    $CMakeExpr+= """$file"" " ;
}
$CMakeExpr+=")"
return $CMakeExpr;
```

Suppose you have a folder with this structure

```
C:\Workspace\A
--a.cpp
C:\Workspace\B 
--b.cpp
```

Now save this file as "generateSourceList.ps1" for example,  and run the script as

```
~>./generateSourceList.ps1 -root "C:\Workspace" > out.txt
```

out.txt file will contain

```
set(SOURCE "A/a.cpp" "B/b.cpp")
```

Comment: Question is tagged cross-platform - powershell is not cross-platform.

Comment: @reichhart powershell works on linux and and mac too

Comment: I know. But there's no tag for powershell and "CMake" is already crossplatform. "Powershell" would be an additional dependency and is very seldom used on other OS than Windows. You might find even more C# developers on Linux than people with powershell. And the most important fact is the question: "Is it possible to do it in directly in CMake? How?"

Comment: Powershell absolutely is cross platform.

Comment: I don't think I will ever install Powershell on my Linux box or on my Mac. Thanks but no thanks. Need another solution.

Comment: I'd sooner use Bash for Linux and Mac then use something like Cygwin to make it work on windows.  But even before that I'd use just CMake.