# CMake configuration

Tags: c, cmake

I have a simple C project structure:

```
proj/
  src/
  docs/
  build/
  tests/
  lib/
```

Trying to write a suitable CMake file.

My attempt so far: http://pastebin.com/846ZzUev

CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:6 (PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR):
  Unknown CMake command "PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR".

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/path/to/proj/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".

**How do I: **

- Force a custom compiler.
- Auto-include all library folders with automatic file detection.
- (PROJECT_ROOT/src and PROJECT_ROOT/lib)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `Unknown CMake command "PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR".` - `PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR` isn't a command, it's a [variable](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#variable:PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR). It looks like you're trying to tell CMake where your code lives - the usual way of doing this is simply placing the `CMakeLists.txt` file in root of the project.
2. "Force a custom compiler." - This is covered in the [FAQ](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_FAQ#How_do_I_use_a_different_compiler.3F).
3. "Auto-include all library folders with automatic file detection." - You mean something like described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3201154/cmake-automatically-add-all-files-in-a-folder-to-a-target)(more discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1027247/best-way-to-specify-sourcefiles-in-cmake))? The idiomatic CMake way of doing this would be to explicitly list the targets with their source files.