# CMake - add_executable called with incorrect number of arguments

Tags: c++, cmake

I am trying to organize a C++ project which starts to have a lot of files. I would like to create two executables which share some source file using Cmake. I have found an interesting procedure here:

[How to add source files in another folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25609692/how-to-add-source-files-in-another-folder?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Below is my version of the thing

```
file(GLOB Common_sources RELATIVE "Common" "*cpp")
file(GLOB Mps_sources RELATIVE "Mps" "*.cpp")                 
file(GLOB Mss_sources RELATIVE "Mss" "*.cpp") 

add_executable(test_mss ${Common_sources} ${Mss_sources}) 
add_executable(test_mps ${Common_sources} ${Mps_sources})
```

But CMake complains

```
CMake Error at src/CMakeLists.txt:44 (add_executable):
add_executable called with incorrect number of arguments

CMake Error at src/CMakeLists.txt:45 (add_executable):
add_executable called with incorrect number of arguments
```

It says to look at `CMakeOutput.log`, but the file is really too long, I can not find useful information.

I checked the CMake documentation, it seems that it can take a second source as an additional argument. https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/add_executable.html

I would like to find the source of this bug. I have the feeling that I am missing something obvious here.

Comment: Check your souces lists. If they are empty, then `add_executable` will fail. You may use something like `message ("Common ${Common_sources}")` to output your sources list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error you get is because source list, passed to `add_executable`, is actually empty.

Correct way for collect sources in `Common/` subdirectory is:

```
file(GLOB Common_sources "Common/*.cpp")
```

---

In command [file(GLOB)](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/command/file.html)  *RELATIVE* option **doesn't specify search directory**. Instead, it just tells CMake to generate *relative paths* instead of absolute:

> If RELATIVE flag is specified, the results will be returned as relative paths to the given path.

Assuming

```
file(GLOB Common_sources "Common/*.cpp")
# gets: /<path-to-source>/Common/my_source.cpp
```

then (also note to *absolute path* in RELATIVE option)

```
file(GLOB Common_sources RELATIVE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Common" "Common/*.cpp")
# gets: my_source.cpp
```

and (when files are not under *RELATIVE* directory)

```
file(GLOB Common_sources RELATIVE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Mps" "Common/*.cpp")
# gets: ../Common/my_source.cpp
```

Comment: It solved my problem. I am just wondering whether it contradicts the first part of the accepted answer here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25609692/how-to-add-source-files-in-another-folder?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Yes, my answer contradicts the referenced one. I have added a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25609692/how-to-add-source-files-in-another-folder#comment87626669_25610377) to that answer.

Answer (score 2):

You have to quote the variables.

```
add_executable(test_mss "${Common_sources}" "${Mss_sources}")
```

Otherwise for an empty variable, CMake replaces the variable by nothing and the number of arguments seems to be wrong.

Similar problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39733128/2799037

Comment: Quoting a variable's dereference, when the variable can be empty, has a sence, but only when empty string is acceptable. In case of `add_executable` empty strings are not acceptable (name of source file cannot be empty). So quoting has no sence with `add_executable`.

Answer (score 0):

None of the suggested answers worked for me.

This works:

```
add_executable(<executable_name> <source_file_name>)
```