# CMake. How to find all files to translate their in Qt5Linguist?

Tags: cmake, qt5, qt-linguist

I am trying to use Qt for my large project with different subprojects. I need to find all `*.cpp` `*.h` `*.ui` files to create `*.ts` files and apply them for `qt5_create_translation`. Could you help me how to do it?

I tried to use

```
file(GLOB ${ALL_USE_FILES} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/*.*)
```

but it won't work.

Comment: The second argument to `find(GLOB)` is a **variable name** (`ALL_USE_FILES`). You should NOT *dereference* it here (`${ALL_USE_FILES}`). See e.g. this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3201211/3440745

Comment: Thanks, but I need to find recursive all files in subdirectories.

Comment: Then use `file(GLOB_RECURSE)` as described in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35433745/3440745. (It is strange that you haven't found it while googling).

Comment: Thanks for the help!!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add all files under a folder to a CMake glob?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35411489/add-all-files-under-a-folder-to-a-cmake-glob)