# How could I match all subdirectories automatically with cmake

Tags: c++, cmake

Provided my project is like this:

```
|--main.cpp
  |-A--a1.cpp
  |   |-a2.cpp
  |
  |-B--b1.cpp
      |-b2.cpp
|--CMakeLists.txt
```

How could I add all the `*.cpp` (e.g `main.cpp`, `A/a1.cpp`, `A/a2.cpp`, `B/b1.cpp`, `B/b2.cpp`) to a cmake variable `SRC` ? I hope I could only need one `CMakeLists.txt`. By the way, what if I need to exclude certain `.cpp`s ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Automatically add all files in a folder to a target using CMake?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3201154/automatically-add-all-files-in-a-folder-to-a-target-using-cmake)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add all files under a folder to a CMake glob?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35411489/add-all-files-under-a-folder-to-a-cmake-glob)

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by Alexander, you can use file(GLOB_RECURSE myVar myRegex) to get all the files matching the myRegex into a myVar as a list. In order to exclude some you could play around with the myRegex, or you could filter the list with `list(FILTER myVar <INCLUDE|EXCLUDE> REGEX <regular_expression>)`

But note that adding another .cpp file to your project will not automatically be added to your target on rebuild. You will need to explicitly reconfigure your project for the changes to be made. Since CMake 3.12 there is also an option `CONFIGURE_DEPENDS` for file GLOBE and GLOBE_RECURSE, that will do the update on rebuild for you.

Here is the NOTE from CMake documentation:

> **Note** We do not recommend using GLOB to collect a list of source files
>   from your source tree. If no CMakeLists.txt file changes when a source
>   is added or removed then the generated build system cannot know when
>   to ask CMake to regenerate. The CONFIGURE_DEPENDS flag may not work
>   reliably on all generators, or if a new generator is added in the
>   future that cannot support it, projects using it will be stuck. Even
>   if CONFIGURE_DEPENDS works reliably, there is still a cost to perform
>   the check on every rebuild.

Answer (score 1):

It's what you want:

```
file(GLOB_RECURSE SRC *.cpp)
```

For more info: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/file.html

For excluding you can write function.

**Note:** But I don't recommend to use 'glob'. 
Better use 'set' with list of files.

Comment: Does this support sub-directory matching ?

Comment: @coincheung Yes, it will traverse all the subdirectories

Comment: Then how could I bypass certain files with some name ?

Comment: This command doesn't have this option, but you can use list(REMOVE_ITEM ... ). https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/list.html