# How to recursively include all levels under the current subdirectory for compilation using cmake?

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, directory

If you have a directory structure with multiple levels, say

```
source
    source/Graphics
        source/Graphics/Camera
            source/Graphics/Camera/Orthographic
    source/math
        source/math/matrices
    source/network
```

How can you isntruct Cmake to travle through the full subdirectory tree and include every single cpp file found?

i.e

```
target_sources(voxel-cone-tracing PUBLIC <All sources go here>)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3201154/1896169 , although it needs the other question as well

Comment: Also, [keep in mind that it's recommended not to do this, but to explicitly list the sources](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1027247/1896169)