# How to create a CMake file to compile all C++ files of a project?

Tags: c++, cmake, g++

I have the following source files:

```
main.cpp game.cpp TextureManager.cpp GameObject.cpp Map.cpp
```

and each of them (apart from `main.cpp`) has a header file with the same name:

```
game.h TextureManager.h GameObject.h Map.h
```

I can now compile my source files through the terminal using the following command:

```
g++ -std=gnu++11 -o executable main.cpp game.cpp TextureManager.cpp GameObject.cpp Map.cpp -lGL -lSDL2 -lSDL
```

What the make file should look like to compile the aforementioned source files and also incorporating the libraries and the `g++ -std=gnu+11`?

Comment: I strongly recommend adding your attempt at the makefile for a couple reasons: 1. It gives answerers a good baseline of what you know that they can compose their answers around. 2. It shows that you have tried and aren't just some slacker trying to crowd source their brain.

Comment: Step 1) learn CMake. Step 2) Write CMakeLists.txt file. There's plenty of [documentation](https://cmake.org/documentation/) available. This is *not* a tutorial site. Do some research. Try things. Learn. Then come back and ask a *specific* question when you get stuck.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Automatically add all files in a folder to a target using CMake?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3201154/automatically-add-all-files-in-a-folder-to-a-target-using-cmake)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)
project (game)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED on)

add_executable(game main.cpp game.cpp TextureManager.cpp GameObject.cpp Map.cpp)
target_link_libraries(game GL SDL2 SDL)
```