# How I can build the big library using cmake?

Tags: cmake, build

I have a lot folders from sources which contents `.cpp` and `.h` files. Each folder contains `CMakeLists.txt` file except folders which contents `.h` headers files. I see the several ways.

1. The first way is consist from take advantage of `add_library(myLib1 STATIC /link/to/sources/somefile.cpp /link/to/sources/interfaces/somefile.h)`. But in this way I will have a lot strings when is't good way, I think. Because I have very more files, which are interconnected.
2. The same way, with that exception when use `set(HEADERS /link1 /link2 ....)` and `set(SOURCES /link3 ...)` and than `add_library(myLib ${HEADERS} ${SOURCES})`.

I think than both the ways is't do properly. I don't know how I can connect the folder with library into my project, because if include this using the above methods it's will take a long time and is't beautiful

Comment: You don't have to list headers.

Comment: Do you ask about the way to specify **all files** in a given directory as **source** files for the library? If yes, then see that question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3201154/automatically-add-all-files-in-a-folder-to-a-target-using-cmake.