# How to compile and link additional source code without including it explicitly into the project?

Tags: xcode, clang

I have a tool that generates additional source code on a build phase in a run script section. I would like to include resulting files of this section into compilation and linking. How it is possible to do? I know  that it is possible to write clang calls in additional run script section but I am looking alternative options, since it will be too complex to keep run script section with clang and project compiler settings in sync.

Files that I am generating is a set of categories to classes currently included into the project. I do not need to worry about importing categories into the project, since all the code that generated automatically imported into generated-categories.h which is imported by default into precompiled header.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can solve this problem by adding a file to your project that contains something like the following:

```
#include "generatedFile1.c"
#include "genreatedFile2.c"
```

And so on.  Then, you just need to make this file (or build phase) depend on (or run after) the source-code generating step.

I'm not very familiar with Xcode, so I don't know specifically how you would accomplish that; hopefully someone with more specific experience can point you in the right direction on that front.

Edit:  I made it work with a simple project here.  Example:

main.m:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "generatedFile.m"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {

        // insert code here...
        NSLog(@"%@", string);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

script.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "NSString *string = @\"Hello, World\";" > ${SYMROOT}/generatedFile.m
```

And then I added `${SYMROOT}` in the "Header search paths" in the project settings and added a "run shell script" phase before the "compile sources" phase.

Comment: That is actually a challenge in Xcode to add files into the compilation phase from the script. :) So the second part is the most important one. Anyway thanks for trying to help :)

Comment: I'm fiddling with it now.  Adding the script phase seemed pretty easy, I just need to figure out how to add the build results directory to the include search path, I think.  Edit:  I have it working by generating the file in `/tmp`, so I'm not far off.

Comment: You know what, it is actually could be an option. Thanks for an idea. I will take a look into it. I will let you know later if it will work for me.  Thanks!

Comment: It works perfectly on my side as well. Thank you very much :)